# How to pass methods and StringProperties through Kivy widget in kv lang

Tags: python, kivy

I'm creating some widgets in kivy to reuse them. How can I pass methods and properties to initialize the new widget? I achive passing strings variable and works well but, what happen with methods and properties?

This is the widget that I want to reuse:

```
<ParameterInput>:
    text: ''
    icon: ''
    suffix: ''
    data: ''
    check_data: ''

    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: root.text + ':'
    BoxLayout:
        Image:
            size_hint_x: 0.2
            source: root.icon
        TextInput:
            text: root.data
            on_text: root.data = self.text
            on_focus: root.check_data(self, self.focus)
        Label:
            text: root.suffix
```

And this is how I want to reuse it:

```
ParameterInput:
    id: temp_param
    text: 'Temperature'
    icon: './images/thermometer.png'
    suffix: '\u00B0' + 'C'
    data: app.parameters.temperature
    check_data: app.parameters.check_temp

ParameterInput:
    id: param_2
    text: 'Param 2'
    icon: './images/param_2.png'
    suffix: '\u00B0' + 'C'
    data: app.parameters.param_2
    check_data: app.parameters.check_param_2
```

Text, icon and suffix work well, because they are just strings, but data is a StringProperty and doesn't update. The other problem is that if I pass a method in check_data the app crash.

**EDIT:**

How can I use MyLayout as a Component like:

```
MyLayout:
    check_data1: app.ch1
    check_data2: app.ch2
```

Where check_data1 and check_data2 are methods of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Dont define `check_data` as a StringProperty if you want a method.
If you want `check_data` to be like a property you can assign a function to, you can do something like this.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class MyLayout(BoxLayout):

    def ch1(self, data):
        return str(data*2)

    def ch2(self, data):
        return str(data*4)


KV = """

MyLayout:
    Button:
        check_data: root.ch1
        text: self.check_data(42)
    Button:
        check_data: root.ch2
        text: self.check_data(42)   

"""

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

TestApp().run()
```